# Can the context from a destroyed service be used

Tags: android, android-service, android-context

I am developing an Android application implementing a given service. 
When this service is created (from external events), it creates and triggers an asynchronous task. This task uses the service itself as Context reference when calling Android APIs such as `context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE)`.

Since the service might be destroyed at any time (also from external events), Service.onDestroy() can be called before the task it triggered has completed. Therefore the task might use the context from a destroyed service when calling Android APIs.

Is it something that must be avoided?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't let the service be destroyed at all. Services are meant to perform uninterrupted until task is completed. Coming to `context` I am not sure whether you know it or not, context is object of Activity or Service, once destroyed, context makes no sense. If you somehow manage to retain the context, then prepare yourself for weeks of debugging to correct these memory leaks.

Comment: *Services are meant to perform uninterrupted until task is completed* if only it were that simple in practice